# GraphQL subscribe puzzler

Tags: websocket, graphql, apollo

Using apollo-link on the client, and PubSub from apollo-server-express on the server. Getting strange result in a mocha test talking to the GraphQL API:

mocha:

```
import { execute, makePromise } from 'apollo-link';

const uri = 'http://localhost:3001/graphql';
const link = new HttpLink({ uri, fetch });

const subscribe = (query, handlers) => {
  const operation = {
    query: gql`${query}`,
  };

  return execute(link, operation).subscribe(handlers);
};


  const handlers = {
    next: (data) => {
      console.log(`received data: ${Date.now()}, ${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}`);
    },
    error: error => console.log(`received error ${error}`),
    complete: () => console.log('complete'),
  };

  it('subscribe', async () => {
    const query = `subscription {
      info
    }`;
    subscribe(query, handlers);
  });
```

Server:

```
try {
  console.log('subscription =>| ', Date.now(), '|', line);
  worker.pubsub.publish('infoTopic', { info: line });
} catch (e) {
  console.error(e);
}
```

Here's what I'm seeing (from test):

> received data: 1545013826838, {   "errors": [
>       {
>         "message": "Cannot return null for non-nullable field Subscription.info.",...

(from server):

> subscription =>|  1545013826887 | info depth 1 seldepth 1 ...

Subscriber is receiving at 826**838**, 
but publisher is sending at 826**887**

What the heck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just recently came upon this error. I found a solution to be I needed the field name of the object published match the field name of the subscription. To illustrate, notice the field name `newPost` in the schema matches the name in the resolver, as well as the field name of the object being published to the channel and the subscription operation:

```
// schema
type Subscription {
    newPost: Post!
}

// subscription resolver
newPost: {
  subscribe(parent, args, { pubsub }, info)
    return pubsub.asyncIterator('new post')
  }
}

// in the event publisher
pubsub.publish('new post', { newPost: post })

// the subscription operation
subscription {
  newPost {
    id
    title
    body
    published
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Jack.  I did finally get it working, though probably by doing exactly what you did above. I posted a hackernoon article about it [here](https://hackernoon.com/graphql-subscriptions-using-apollo-2-3eb3184768c4).